# Matlab Mex32 link error while compiling Felzenszwalb VOC on Windows

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm compiling a C file (part of [voc-release](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~pff/latent/) library)  with Matlab and I'm getting the error below.
I can't seem to solve it. Could anyone tell me what causes this error and what I can do about it?

```
    mex -O features.cc
    Writing library for features.mexw32 
    c:\users\safaa\appdata\local\temp\mex_ty~1\features.obj .text: undefined reference to '_round' 
    C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2009A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'features.mexw32' failed.
```

Comment: What mex compiler are you using? See `mex -setup`.

Comment: I've tried the two compilers via this instruction "mex -setup"
the one included in matlab and the visual c++ 
the first one runs on some files but the second one doesn't run on the those files , .h files fatal errors

Answer (score 2):

If you had included more of the error message, I believe that this would have
already been answered, just an FYI.  It looks like you're compiling a file
from some non-matlab source, which is fine, but you're likely going to have to
give more information about it.  It appears that the features.cc file is
referencing a symbol `round` which is why you're getting the error.  You'll need
to provide the library for the function, or compile it from source.  If you do
a `help mex`, it should be able to give you information about the library linker
commands `-L` for the path and `-l` for the library.  I seem to remember that
this feature doesn't work exactly as advertised, and requires you to use 
`-lC:/path/to/library/libfile.lib`, or whatever.  First of all, I would recommend
compiling the `yprime` example from the Matlab help.  This will ensure that you
have your compiler setup correctly, which it sounds likel you do.  Also, take a
look at the yprime.c file and the `mexFunction`.  You may want to make sure the
compiler will accept a `.cc` file as a C file.  It may interpret it as a C++
file which will cause you more headaches.  You could rename the `yprime.c` file
to `yprime.cc` just to test the idea.

**EDIT**
Thanks for providing the code.  This should be cake my friend, complete cake.  :-)

This is my error I get when I try to compile using:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express

>> mex -v -g features.c
This is mex, Copyright 1984-2007 The MathWorks, Inc. 

-> Default options filename found in C:\Documents and Settings\wynkocl\Application\Data\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2009b 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
->    Options file           = C:\Documents and Settings\wynkocl\Application Data\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2009b\mexopts.bat 
      MATLAB                 = C:\MATLAB\R2009B~1 
->    COMPILER               = cl 
->    Compiler flags: 
         COMPFLAGS           = /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD 
         OPTIMFLAGS          = /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG 
         DEBUGFLAGS          = /Z7 
         arguments           =  
         Name switch         = /Fo 
->    Pre-linking commands   =  
->    LINKER                 = link 
->    Link directives: 
         LINKFLAGS           = /dll /export:mexFunction /LIBPATH:"C:\MATLAB\R2009B~1\extern\lib\win32\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /incremental:NO /implib:"C:\DOCUME~1\WYNKOCL\LOCALS~1\TEMP\MEX_7L~1\templib.x" /MAP:"features.mexw32.map" 
         LINKDEBUGFLAGS      = /DEBUG /PDB:"features.mexw32.pdb" 
         LINKFLAGSPOST       =  
         Name directive      = /out:"features.mexw32" 
         File link directive =  
         Lib. link directive =  
         Rsp file indicator  = @ 
->    Resource Compiler      = rc /fo "mexversion.res" 
->    Resource Linker        =  
---------------------------------------------------------------- 


--> cl  /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /FoC:\DOCUME~1\WYNKOCL\LOCALS~1\TEMP\MEX_7L~1\features.obj -IC:\MATLAB\R2009B~1\extern\include -IC:\MATLAB\R2009B~1\simulink\include /Z7 -DMX_COMPAT_32 features.c 

features.c 
features.c(27) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type' 
features.c(28) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type' 
features.c(92) : warning C4013: 'round' undefined; assuming extern returning int 

  C:\MATLAB\R2009B~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'features.c' failed.
```

Ahhh...now we can find the issue.  First, the C2059 error is do to the fact the the function `max` is being redefined, I'm pretty sure on that because that's how I fixed it.  Then the `round` function has no prototype.  Hmmm, that's odd.  Well, that's because `round` is not in `math.h` so you'll need to [implement one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58289/C-Round-Function) like at the top of your file like so:

```
int round(double number)
{
  return (number >= 0) ? (int)(number + 0.5) : (int)(number - 0.5);
}
```

Now it compiles!  As a tip, you can also try `mex -v -g` when you build to get more verbose debugging messages.  Hope this gets you on your way!

Here's the last of what I've got here:

1. Re-download voc-release4.01.tgz
2. Extract and rename all `.cc` files `.cpp` files.
3. Open the `compile.m` script and modify like so:

   mex -v -g resize.cpp
   mex -v -g dt.cpp
   mex -v -g features.cpp
   mex -v -g getdetections.cpp

   % use one of the following depending on your setup
   % 0 is fastest, 3 is slowest

   % 0) multithreaded convolution using SSE
   % mex -v -g fconvsse.cpp -o fconv

   % 1) multithreaded convolution using blas
   %    WARNING: the blas version does not work with matlab >= 2010b 
   %    and Intel CPUs
   % mex -O fconvblasMT.cpp -lmwblas -o fconv

   % 2) mulththreaded convolution without blas
   % mex -O fconvMT.cpp -o fconv

   % 3) convolution using blas
   mex -g -v fconvblas.cpp -LC:\MATLAB\R2009bSP1\extern\lib\win32\microsoft -lmwblas -output fconv

   % 4) basic convolution, very compatible
   % mex -O fconv.cpp -o fconv

I recommend staying with option 3, pthreads is likely just a little too much for you at this point in time.  :-)

1. resize.cpp

Add
    #define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)
    int round(double number)
    {
      return (number >= 0) ? (int)(number + 0.5) : (int)(number - 0.5);
    }
at the top and change:

```
alphainfo ofs[len];
```

to

```
alphainfo * ofs = (alphainfo *)mxMalloc(len);
```

and

```
assert(sy-1 >= 0);
```

to
    assert(sy1 >= 0);
don't forget to `mxFree(ofs);` at the end of the function.

1. dt.cpp: Change all `int32_t` to `int32_T`.
2. features.cpp
   Add

   int round(double number)
   {
     return (number >= 0) ? (int)(number + 0.5) : (int)(number - 0.5);
   }
3. Make sure you have a directory `C:\MATLAB\R2009bSP1\extern\lib\win32\microsoft`, if not put your Matlab release extern library directory there.

Enjoy.

Comment: I've tried other files c & cc and they compile correctly
but with others like the features.cc m it's giving me that error and with the rest it says that there are missing header files !!
when I bring them all and put them in the "include directory "
the errors turned to be in the header files itself !!! 
It's driving me crazy , I can't find the solution !
some pages on the net says that there is a windows error :S 
I couldn't understand all your reply :$

Comment: @PureSoul would you consider posting your features.cc file?

Comment: sure , I don't know If it's allowed to post it here :$

Comment: Actually that's not my code , There's a tool called "voc-release4.01"
[link] http://www.cs.brown.edu/~pff/latent/
and features.cc is a file from it , there were a horrible mistakes in the c files !!! I fixed them all , yet still this linking problem and the missing libraries
I just want to make this tool runs , I really need it in my work :(

Comment: It's compiling !!!!!!!!! :D 
so many Big Thank you Mr.macduff
I'm gonna try to compile the other files now :)

Comment: [link] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62218293/fconvsse.cc
This one was giving me errors related to a missing library and after I searched the net and put in in the include folder the errors are now from the .h file itself !!!
------------------------
[link] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62218293/getdetections.cc
and this one is giving me errors related to parameters passing by reference in the prototype of the function , do you know what's the problem ?

Comment: I've fixed the errors in the " getdetections.cc "
please help me with the other one ! 
I can't find the Bug :(

Comment: I really appreciate your help , I did as you said but matlab becomes stupid !   C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2009A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'resize.cpp' not found. 
I've changed the path , still it's not working

Comment: I'm sorry , but the code itself of the cc files contains errors !!
changing it from cc to ccp didn't help :(
I'll stay on my files that I had fixed one by one !
one problem remains that there's a missing library <pthread.h>
I downloaded it then it asked me to get another one called <sched.h>
and I did it , now all the errors come from this sched.h !!! 
can you try it on your laptop ? 
here are the missing headers :
[link]http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62218293/missing%20.h.rar
thank you so much , try the "fconvsse.cc"file